# How to dynamically populate a gridview where the dataset column length is not static/known

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I've a datatable where the number of columns are not static, like it can contain 10 column or it may contain more than that. Now I want to display it in a GridView. HOW CAN I DO THAT ?

Comment: Please search it a little before as a genera question like this, -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488562.aspx

Comment: I already searched these links but I was unable to get the gist, like what exactly should work for me. So can you please help me in getting more help on my question ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must show here what you have find and where did you stuck

Comment: @SuryadipBasu First learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question here